# Sketch won't load from Arduino IDE to ESP-12F

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide

I was working quite a long time with ESP-01, and trying to move to ESP-12 due to lack of GPIO ports.
I'm having hard time to run code on the ESP-12 and can't understand the problem.  I've wired the ESP to work on boot on mode 1:

```
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(1,6)
```

and uploaded a simple code:

```cpp
void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(74880);
  Serial.println("Hello, world");
}
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);              // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);              // wait for a second
}
```

The upload ends successfully, but when moving to mode 3 (run mode) I get nothing!

```
     ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)
load 0x4010f000, len 1264, room 16 
tail 0
chksum 0x0f
csum 0x0f
~ld
```

By nothing I mean that hooking a LED to pin 13 yields with nothing (constant ON), and even no Serial print!

What am I missing!?

Comment: You don't really give any indication of how you are powering the esp, are you using a clean 3V3 source? Anyhow - I'd strongly advise signing up for the esp8266 forums and getting familiar with the search function -stackoverflow is for programming related questions and this is clearly a hardware issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am getting exactly same error with you and didnt find any solution.